# Interpolation of surface normals on the face of a triangle and Goroud shading

Tags: opengl, graphics, shader, render

My question is detailed at this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337452/interpolation-of-surface-normals-on-the-face-of-a-triangle-and-goroud-shading).

I linked it instead of copy paste because here I can't seem to get the fancy math symbols to show properly here.

Thoughts?

Comment: -1: My thoughts are that you shouldn't ask questions by proxy.

Comment: @NicolBolas I agree but considering it's just a different stackexchange site and It portrays the question better than I could here I don't see the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your question is much longer than the whole theory behind gouraud and phong shading.
And the confusing mathematical symbols are not typical in conputer graphics:

so in two sentences:
gouraud shading bilinearily interpolates the colors at the vertices. you cannot have a higlight with that.
Later phong shading was invented, it works bettet for curved surfaces, showing a higlight becuase of the normal interpolation.

**And now in one sentence:**

gouraud interpolates the corner colors, while phong interpolates the normals

Update: gouraud shading used the color of the corners of the face. the color is calculated by the surface normal at that corner. for rounded objects aproximated by a triangukation or other meshes still the corners ate relevant. for each corner one color is calculated, by taking the normal at that corner. in case of rounded meshees one would take the average of the neighbouring faces center normals.
 for cubes one would not use the average of the neighbouring faces. 
then gozraud shading colors the face by a bilinear interpolation of the 3 colors. if you habe more then three corners, then you have to triangulate the face first.

Comment: by flat faces do you mean the face has to have the same normals on every vertex? This makes sense. But I thought the proof in the question meant that it had to work even for curved surfaces?

Comment: no normals can be different

Comment: Update: i removed the word flat, and rewrote the answer